# Test array to include an object with a certain key: value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

As the title says we found our selves in a situation where we need to check if an array contains an element that one of his properties equals to something.

We tried and search for a couple of hours until we desided to raise an issue about it.
We were able to solve the problem like this:

```
const playersRegs = created.gameLog.filter(e => e.nameType === eventTypes.PlayerReg);
expect(playersRegs).to.have.lengthOf(1);
```

but we were hoping for something a bit like:

```
expect(created.gameLog).to.include.something.that.has.property('nameType', eventTypes.PlayerReg);
```

if we missed anything  please let us know and if we didnt please consider adding this functionality ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chai-things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things/) looks to be exactly what you are looking for

and your example

```
expect(created.gameLog).to.include.something.that.has.property('nameType', eventTypes.PlayerReg);
```

is exactly the syntax of it

Answer (score 2):

You can use .some() instead:

```
const hasPlayersReg = created.gameLog.some(e => e.nameType === eventTypes.PlayerReg);
expect(hasPlayersReg).to.be.true;
```

Or .find() like this:

```
const playersReg = created.gameLog.find(e => e.nameType === eventTypes.PlayerReg);
expect(playersReg ).to.not.be.undefined;
```

The rest seems perfectly fine.

Comment: `find` returns `undefined` if there's no matching element. Probably better to use `some` which always returns `true` or `false` ?

Comment: Good point. But chai also has an undefined check so I updated. Added the some because it is indeed even better

Comment: Is there any way I can write the whole test in one expect ? like: expect(created.gameLog).to.include.something.that.has.property('nameType', eventTypes.PlayerReg);

Comment: You can look at http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_nested or http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep but I personally would prefer keeping it simple.